# Why was this question moved?

Tags: discussion, support

I'm referring to [Name for this sort of word?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/456894/name-for-this-sort-of-word).  I didn't understand the reason they gave.  And how do you find the "chat" dept.?

If this isn't in the right "dept.", then please move it.  If it's in the wrong dept., then it's bec. I don't see any others.

Thanx!

Answer (score 5):

The question wasn't moved at all. In addition, I don't see anyone suggesting it should be moved nor are there any close votes (of any type).

What you're referring to is probably the message that says "Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?", which is automatically shown after you've had a certain amount of back and forth in the comments section (according to [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/300466/323179), it's triggered when two users have four comments each, responding to each other—it looks like Mari-Lou A is the other user in this equation).

Unfortunately, you need 20 reputation to chat. (Yeah, the system is messed up, but there's apparently [a reason it can't be fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/98791/323179). Still, I remember being in this exact same situation when I first started.)

The best thing you can do right now is to **edit your question**, which can be done by going to the question and clicking "edit" (you should end up [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/456894/edit)) and adding the relevant information from [this comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/456894/name-for-this-sort-of-word#comment1099536_456894) and [this comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/456894/name-for-this-sort-of-word#comment1099510_456894) into the post, then delete the comments. You could also delete most of the other comments, since it's [not necessary](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) to leave compliments.

Unrelated tip: when you're commenting to reply to another user, make sure to prefix their name with `@` to ensure they'll be alerted to your comment.

Anyways, welcome to the site. I hope you'll stick around and earn the privilege to chat ;)

Comment: Ack. I hadn't seen this post. Well, despite the words of wisdom, the OP didn't edit, so I did it for him. I like the question. Pity, I forgot to add the [comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/456894/is-there-a-term-for-an-equivocal-compound-e-g-guinea-pig#comment1099510_456894) explaining why learners find these compound nouns tricky. If @Wordster is listening that's something they could edit in.

Comment: Yes, Laurel, that was exactly the msg. I was reacting to with this question.  Thank you for the other info, as well.  I will go and delete the compliments right now.  Mari-Lou, thanx to you as well for all your help here and at the original question.  I only just got online a few minutes ago, so I'm "behind" on fixing things.